# Return a value from send function

Tags: solidity, web3js, blockchain, remix, ethereumjs

Hi guys i have one really big problem. 
I have this pice of code

```
function showInfo(uint _pesel) public onlyMainPerson(msg.sender) returns (string memory, string memory) {
    string memory x = showName(_pesel);
    string memory y = showDate(_pesel);
    return(x,y);
}

function showName(uint _pesel) private view returns( string memory) {
    return(wills[_pesel].name);
}
function showDate(uint _pesel) private view returns( string memory) {
    return(wills[_pesel].date);
}
```

And i want to use it in my web app, i'm doing it by

```
 const names = await this.state.contract.methods.showInfo(123).send({from: this.state.account}, (e) => {
        console.log("done")
        console.log(names);
    })
    console.log(names);
```

But it is not working! It only shows "undefinded". How to solve it? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems here:

1. You are executing your function on-chain, thus you cannot catch returned value.
2. `send` method returns transaction hash, not function call result.

The simplest way to fix this would be to mark your function as `view` and execute off-chain via `call` method:

```solidity
function showInfo(uint _pesel) public view onlyMainPerson(msg.sender) returns (string memory, string memory) {
  string memory x = showName(_pesel);
  string memory y = showDate(_pesel);
  return(x,y);
}
```

```js
const names = await this.state.contract.methods.showInfo(123).call(
  {from: this.state.account});
console.log(names);
```

See [documentation](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.4/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-call) for details.

Comment: This attempt at unfolding a confusing topic might help: https://blog.b9lab.com/calls-vs-transactions-in-ethereum-smart-contracts-62d6b17d0bc2

Comment: Yes but there is a problem because i dont know how to send msg.sender in call function.

Comment: If i was able to do it would fix my problem ^^

Comment: As I said in my answer, see documentation for details: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.4/web3-eth-contract.html#id29 . BTW, you may set arbitrary msg.sender address, even address you don't have private key for.

Comment: Ok, thats it what i've been looking for! Thanks!